# Why is there an offset in the Java String implementation?

Tags: java, string, implementation

I've been looking at the implementation and I don't understand why there is an offset. I assume it is important.

I'm taking an Algorithms course taught by Sedgewick, and we're talking about Strings now. In lecture he briefly discussed the String implementation, but he doesn't go over why there is an offset (Note, if lectures were not online, I would definitely have asked).

It seems when one makes a String that within the implementation, it is given an offset, and I can't seem to understand why one is needed. Even for substring purposes I don't quite follow why you would have an offset. For example, apparently if you create a string `"David"`, it is really `['X', 'X', 'D', 'a', 'v', 'i', 'd', 'X']`, or something of that nature, where it is offset by the `'X'`s. Why is this?

Comment: Which Java version are you looking at? Oracle's JDK 7 implementation doesn't use an offset field anymore.

Comment: Before Java 7 update 4, a String could point to a portion of another String so it need to know where that portion started.

Comment: Nice question!  I've always assumed that the reason for the offset was so that you could do `split` and `substring` and so on, without having to copy the backing array.  But I have no evidence that that was the actual rationale behind the decision to implement it that way.

Comment: I have added more content to the question. @DavidWallace, I'm not sure how offsetting would help that as well.

Comment: Well, what I mean is that if you do `"David asked a good question".split(" ");`, then the resulting `"David", "asked", "a", "good"` and `"question"` can all share the same character array as the original `String`, but just have different offsets and lengths, so that they show different parts of the array.  That way, the characters themselves never need to be copied.

Comment: Ah, gotcha! I see how that could be beneficial. It makes sense for offsets in that regard. I suppose I'm fuzzy in that in the example, the professor stated `['X', 'X', 'D', 'a', 'v,'i', 'd', 'X']` as the representation of `"David"`, and I found it perplexing as to why the `'X'`s are on both sides. I feel as though offsetting with the split operation could be done just as well with `['D', 'a', 'v', 'i', 'd']`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be useful in cases where strings need to be derived from another longer string, akin to substring().

In this case the same (immutable) backing array may be used, while adjusting the offset and length, to save memory and optimize performance.

This is no longer the case in JDK7.

Comment: So essentially, are you saying that if I have for example `['X', 'X', 'D', 'a', 'v', 'i', 'd', 'X']`, that I could use this exact same array , but the offset would change, so whenever I performed anything, it would simply perform it on a subset of this array? For example, if the offset there is 2, and I want `'vid'`, the offset would become 4, and based on that I could make all calculations necessary while preserving space?

Comment: @David Yes, precisely. This is what allows a substring to be so easily computed: It uses the backing array with different offsets; the evaluation simply changes when the string is used(for example in a `System.out.println()`).

Comment: @David Actually, I misread your comment. That's not fully correct. When the string is created(assuming no optimization trickery) it will be just `['D', 'a', 'v', 'i', 'd']`. When you start calling substrings, splits, and the like, you'll see parts of this backing array used.

Answer (score 1):

The offsets typically are present as an optimization.  For example, in the character array related items, you can use the same character array multiple times to construct multiple Strings from the array.  This is because you would use the same array with different offsets and lengths.

This is a very effective optimization because it prevents the need to construct new character arrays solely for the purpose of having the character you wish to start with at the zero index.  For example, after reading in a block of bytes (perhaps from a socket), you could chunk it up into String sized messages without having to do unnecessary byte copying.